# Show Current Approved Version in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-approval

I have an issue with my SharePoint list I have created.

I need to be able to make so that one of my views shows all items with
 "Current Approved Version". Is there a way or a setting so that I can make this happen?

As my view is setup now is that, every time an item is edited or added, it needs approval. But thats when I run in to trouble. The status of the item is then changed to "Pending" status and it´s no longer on my approved list view, until I approved the change, and then it creates a new version, wich means the status goes back to "Approved" and the Item can now be found in my approved list view.

What I want is to be able to keep the "Current Approved Version" listed on my approved list view. I don't want it to disappear. Because if I Need to see the full list of all my approved Items then some of them won't be visible because they are in "Pending" status. But the item is still approved, I just have not approved the latest changes.

Does anybody understand what I mean?
Please help

Kind Regards

Stefan Spirovski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is the content approval process - this [MS link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08) has more info on this.

From your description it sounds as though your view has a filter on it, the filter is on a `Status` field and is filtering out anything that does not have the value of `Approved`.  If you remove the filter, users will see both `Approved` and `Pending` documents.

Depending on your Document Library Settings for [Draft Item Security](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37) users will only see `Approved` versions or can see certain draft (Pending) documents too.  For instance if User A created a new draft version 2.1, they might see this draft, whereas User B would only see the `Approved` version 2.0.  The behaviour of 'who can see v2.1 and who cannot' is customisable in the Document Library Settings.

If a document has an existing approved version (i.e. Version 1.0 or Version 2.0) then that version will be visible to all users.  If there is not yet a Version 1.0 (so you only have minor version), the document will not be visible to all users (Site Admin, Owners or users with the 'Full Control' permissions will be able to see it; plus other users, dependent on how the Document Library **Draft Item Security** has been configured).

Comment: Hi Tally, Thank you for the answer. you are right, I do have a filter on my view filtering out anything that does not have the value of "approved". Is there a way to change this filter so that the value "Approved" is only the "Current Approved"??

Comment: Hi Stefan, you can use 'Draft Item Security' to manage this instead of using filters.  Therefore you can either modify the existing view (remove the filter) or else create a new view without the filter.  Depending on how you configure Draft Item Security, you can automatically remove draft items from view for users.  Please bear in mind that the Permissions (aka Groups) that a user is in will affect the behaviour of which documents are displayed or not - as I mentioned in my 4th paragraph.  You may want to do user testing on the view once you have set up the draft item security.